# How to check if string exists in variable output?

Tags: php

Here's what I'm running:

```
echo $checknetworks;
```

Here's the results of the `echo`:

```
Facebook,Twitter,Myspace,Google,Instagram,Pinterest
```

What I want to do is check to see if the string `google` is in the results above.  I do not want it to be case sensitive because the capitalization changes from time to time.

Basically if `google` exists in the string, I want to display "FOUND".  If it doesn't exist, I want to display "NOT FOUND".

I came across a couple of somewhat similar questions here but none seemed to take capitalization into account.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words

Comment: [php:stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php)

Comment: There is `stristr()` that is case insensitive and you could also use `explode()` and loop through the array to see if *google* is found but then you need to convert the `strtolower()` But we are not here to write you a code, show us what you have instead of only displaying the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [stripos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php):

> stripos — Find the position of the first occurrence of a case-insensitive substring in a string

```
$checknetworks = "Facebook,Twitter,Myspace,Google,Instagram,Pinterest";

if (stripos($checknetworks, 'Google') === FALSE)
{
    echo 'NOT FOUND';
} else
{
    echo 'FOUND';
}
```

Please note that you should compare types as well. I.e. if your string would start with `google`, `stripos` will return `0`, that would be interpreted as `false`, unless you make the type comparison with `===`

Answer (score 0):

try using [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
<?php
$strVar = (string)$myVar;
if (strpos($strVar, "Google")){
    echo "Found"
}else{
    echo "Not found"
}
?>
```

> EDIT:

You must check if the strpos returns FALSE, and not the position 0.
Use '===':

```
if (strpos($strVar, "Google") === FALSE){
```

Comment: if `Google` is the first occurrence in the string like `Google,Facebook,Pinterest`, your solution will return `false`. Because you're comparing the result only, not types...